# start ddclient as daemon with systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, systemd, daemon

I'm trying to start ddclient as daemon in my Ubuntu 15.04, which now uses `systemd`, but was unable to even following the Ubuntu wiki at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS to words.

I've done,

```
update-rc.d ddclient defaults
```

Then tried with,

```
invoke-rc.d ddclient start
```

and then,

```
service ddclient start
```

but `ps` listing still have no `ddclient` in sight.

It is only after I did,

```
/etc/init.d/ddclient restart
```

that I start to see `ddclient` show up in `ps` listing.

Isn't `/etc/init.d/ddclient restart` supposed to be deprecated? Shouldn't we use `invoke-rc.d ... start` or `service ... start` instead?

What's the proper way to start ddclient as daemon under Ubuntu 15.04 systemd?
What's the proper way to make it always start at machine boot? I suppose the `update-rc.d` would be no longer working, as `invoke-rc.d`, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can interact with systemd services through the [systemctl command](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html). If your package management system has provided a systemd [service file](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) with the ddclient package then you can start the service with:

```
[sudo] systemctl start ddclient.service
```

And query the status of the service with:

```
[sudo] systemctl status ddclient.service
```

**Note**: `systemctl start <service>` does not persist across boots. You must `systemctl enable <service>` to include it in the install target, ie multi-user mode, etc.

Looking at the [package source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/ddclient/vivid/files/head:/debian/) it doesn't seem as though they provide a service file for ddclient. I don't actively use ubuntu so I am not aware of how the migration to systemd as an init service is planned but it may require an issue for the package. They have provided a [guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) for the concurrent use of both upstart and systemd.

Comment: Of course [the first rule for migrating to systemd](http://askubuntu.com/a/626858/43344) does apply; and one can find many `ddclient.service` units on the WWW.

Comment: it's not my style to wait so long to respond, but I still need to get over my system freeze (http://superuser.com/questions/927497/force-check-all-file-systems-in-ubuntu) before I can get back to you. Sorry.