# Force check all file systems in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fsck

How to force check all file systems under Linux/Ubuntu?

My newly installed Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid stops booting after the suspend/resume failed. Is there any easy way to force check all the file systems that I have on my machine?

My intuitive thinking is to list all Linux devices, then prefix them with `fsck` to check them each. However, That'd failed for the `btrfs` file systems. `fsck` will complains "bad super blocks". `fsck.btrfs` will do nothing but to tell me to use a different tool. Hence my question.

While trying to find the answer myself, I found this Arch Wiki
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fsck#Forcing_the_check
which suggests passing `fsck.mode=force` as a kernel parameter. But I used it in my Ubuntu 14.10, and it seems not working as none of the disks are  force checked. Morover, the Wiki says it *"will check every filesystem you have on the machine"*, but I'm not sure it is actually every filesystem in `fstab` or every filesystem on the machine.

Comment: How are you determining a lack of  fsck at boot?   and it would be EVERYTHING even stuff MOST users see or  actively use like /dev/pts /dev/shm /var/www   just a few  common  (odd to most users )   that would /are checked Personally I'd be  more worried as to the cause of your  suspend/resume failures   personal experience  lends me to think a  faulty /etc/fstab or options there  for that ....

Comment: *"How are you determining a lack of fsck at boot?"* Easy, I always boot with verbose on (`quiet` off), and know exactly what kernel is doing at any given moment. *"a faulty /etc/fstab"*, no not at all. It *has always been working* fine, under a suspend  failed to resume. *"Personally I'd be more worried as to the cause of your suspend/resume failures"* quite agree, I was thinking to ask that instead, but was afraid the topic would be too broad. Will ask...

Comment: Amend above, It has always been working fine, *until* a suspend failed to resume. For asking the question, Ah, nah, now remember that I saw boot message "ext4 mount takes too loog", and btrfs stack trace after I've waited more than 10 minutes. So I'll focus on this question instead.

Comment: any  recent changes?   updates lv/vg/pvre{name|size} ?

Comment: No, not those significant changes. I normally don't touch my system after installation, not even auto updates -- I do updates only manually. The only change I can think of is adding ddclient, http://superuser.com/questions/925005/start-ddclient-as-daemon-with-systemd

Comment: I want to stress again, that suspend failed to resume is very suspicious to me. This Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid is newly installed, and the suspend had been working fine until the last one. It's a laptop, so I kept doing suspend/resume for about 8 times, then it froze the system. My Ubuntu 14.10's suspend/resume has been working fine since installed, till now. Same laptop.

Comment: how much ram and is it  outrunning ram or battery power ?

Comment: In short, they are not the problems. I appreciate your enthusiasm to help, I really do, but please don't assume that I will make silly mistakes as you've listed, proof for fsck, fstab, recent changes, ram size, or battery power. I'm a programmer. I've been using Linux for over 15 years. I've been even opening up kernel to fix things for me. I know what I'm doing. Besides, the saying "everything has been working fine, until a suspend failed to resume" should have answered all your above questions. Also, please remember, extended discussions in comments should be avoided. Thanks all the same.